# More Constituent badges than Caucus badges?

Tags: support, badges, election

On the Math Stack Exchange site, I apparently have earned more [Constituent badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/208/constituent?userid=72) than [Caucus badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/207/caucus?userid=72), which seems odd—doesn't voting in an election (which grants the Constituent badge) necessitate visiting an election during the voting phase (which should grant a Caucus badge)?  How could I have earned a Constituent badge but not a Caucus badge for the first election?

Comment: Vote by proxy, maybe? *runs*